# Is it possible to get list of videos that suggested my youtube video via youtube api?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need a list of videos that suggest my Youtube video. Is it even possible to fetch something like that from Youtube API?

can't seem to find anything in documentation. Maybe I've missed something. There is relatedToVideoId but i think that doesn't satisfy my requirement.

Comment: I suggest asking the youtube staff